# Nokia HERE maps: Trigger Public Transport through code

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I want to trigger 'Public Transport' toggle button's action through code.

[image]

I have searched everywhere but I couldn't find any resource on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `baseMapType` of the `Display` using the standard setter as shown:

```
map.set("baseMapType", nokia.maps.map.Display.SMART_PT)
```

And then you can reset to normal by,

```
map.set("baseMapType", nokia.maps.map.Display.NORMAL)
```