# Changing the position of components

Tags: javascript, here-api

I can add components to the map via initial settings as below:

```
map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(
    document.getElementById( "map-canvas" ), {
        // Zoom level for the map
        zoomLevel: 6,
        // Map center coordinates
        center: [ 0, 0 ], // not real values
        components: [
             // ZoomBar provides an UI to zoom the map in & out
             new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(), 
             // We add the behavior component to allow panning / zooming of the map
             new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
             new nokia.maps.map.component.Traffic()
        ]
    }
);
```

However, it adds `Traffic` component to the top-left of the page, I have a fixed top bar so I cannot see the component.

I want to change the position of that component let's say bottom-right. I couldn't find anything related in neither documentation nor Internet (or maybe I'm missing some points).

Does the API have a feature like that or do I have to use CSS to change?

EDIT: My Solution:

I ended up playing with CSS although I'm curious about other type of solutions.

```
$( ".nm_MapSettingsWrap" )
      .removeClass( "nm_right" )
      .css( "position", "absolute" )
      .css( "bottom", "20px" )
      .css( "right", "5px" )
   .parent()
   .css( "bottom", "-7px" )
   .removeClass( "nm_top" );
```

I'm not using HERE maps anymore, so my solution is a bit old and I might make mistake about class removals as I don't remember very well, but the idea is to play with CSS of `nm_MapSettingsWrap` class and its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside the DOM generated by the map you will find the following elements:

```
<div class="ovi_mp_mapScheme_normal ovi_mp_hover" style="z-index: 0;"><div class="ovi_mp_controls" style="z-index: 0; font-size: 1em;">
...
   <div class="nm_arrangeableAnchor nm_right">
...
      <ul class="nm_mapSettingsWrap nm_left nm_layout_horizontal" aria-role="menubar" aria-expanded="false">
...
        <li class="nm_trafficIncidents nm_wrap" aria-hidden="true" aria-role="menuitemradio">
            ... etc.
        </li>
        <li class="nm_traffic nm_wrap" aria-hidden="false" aria-role="menuitemradio" title="Traffic conditions" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
                    ... etc
      </li>
```

You should be able to use something like jQuery to obtain the node and alter the CSS classes from `nm_left` to `nm_right` and `nm_middle` to `nm_top` etc. Further adjustments can be made by adding custom styling to these elements.

Alternatively add a **custom button component** yourself and CSS style it to the position you want as in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122478/nokia-here-maps-api) and switch map types programmatically as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103764/nokia-here-maps-trigger-public-transport-through-code)

Comment: I edited my question and added my solution. You are right, I should play with CSS to change position, no other solutions seem exist.